Compare two pdfs for the same figure
The essence of my problem: I have a lot of incoming PDFs, but for work I don't need all of them, only PDFs from a certain supplier. I defined keywords and coordinates of keywords that only this supplier has, and drew lines between the coordinates. I got a figure by which I can compare documents and filter out unnecessary ones. That is, this figure is a kind of template by which I will find the files I need. I saved this figure template as a pdf file. For an example, look below.

Next, I draw the figures (according to the keywords and coordinates) on each PDF file that came to me and look for the figure I need (In this example, this word "INVOICE").

And now the question: how can I compare the first pdf (template) and the second one to understand whether the second pdf matches the required template or not?
I searched for information on the Internet but found nothing similar. Perhaps you could share links/code.
I do not exclude the possibility that I am using the right solution to solve my problem, so I will be glad to hear ideas on this matter.

You definitely can use opencv which has functionality of pattern matching.

Most modern PDF files contain XMP metadata. If you could find identifying information in that, it would be ideal because a) XMP metadata must not be compressed in a PDF file (and that is pretty nicely obeyed), and b) you can scan for XMP metadata packages without understanding the PDF format (so you don't even need to parse the file, just scan it). Adobe even had an XMP toolkit; not sure that is still alive today.
